# How to run these promises in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, es6-promise

So the code below will show you that I am trying to read athelets and departments from a file.

A department has a list of athletes, so first I want to map each athlete of that department and assign that list of athletes to the department. The console logs are there to show the following: imagine that each department has 5 athletes each.

So I want the `console.log("TEST_1")` to print 5 times and `console.log("TEST_2")` to print 1 time, all of this for each department.

```
var array1 = [];
await Promise.all(departaments.map(async dp => {

        array1 = [];
        await Promise.all(athletes.map(async at => {

            var athlete = new Athlete();
            athlete.name = at.name;
            athlete.weight = at.weight;

            array1.push(athlete._id);
            athlete.save();
                        console.log("TEST_1");

        })).then(() => {

            var dep = new Department();
            dep.name = dp.name;
            Object.assign(dep.athletes, array1);

            dep.save();
            console.log("TEST2");
        });
    })).then(async () => {
    ............not relevant..............
}
```

But what this code is doing is: printing all the "TEST_1" and only then "TEST_2" therefore it places the last 5 atheletes in all departments.

I tried changing the `async` and the `await` but it doesn't work...

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure i understand what the code actually does. Also i think you missed that using "await" frees you from using .then() and .catch() from Promises. But i'd guess you'd have to change it to:

```
var array1 = [];
await Promise.all(departaments.map(async dp => {

        array1 = [];
        await Promise.all(athletes.map(async at => {

            var athlete = new Athlete();
            athlete.name = at.name;
            athlete.weight = at.weight;

            await athlete.save();

            // maybe wait till the ORM's .save() operation provides an id?
            array1.push(athlete._id);

                        console.log("TEST_1");

        }));

        var dep = new Department();
        dep.name = dp.name;
        Object.assign(dep.athletes, array1);    

        await dep.save();

        console.log("TEST2");

    })).then(async () => {
    ............not relevant..............
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply yet this alternative now places all athletes inside each department, the file I'm reading has 5 athletes in each department.

Comment: There are only "departaments" and "athletes" variables. You should extend your initial question and show us what the variables/files look like. It depends on that on how you loop though your data and when to created users/departments and assign who to which.